# Is this robotics?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Take a look at https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/364/building-an-alarm-clock. If we *put aside* the fact that it's broad, not clearly stated, and not really a question, is it still suitable for this site?

More clearly, is "anything that uses an Arduino/RPi/etc to do some task" considered on-topic here (provided it is a good question in all other aspects)? Or do we restrict "robotics" to "thingies with a mechanical+electrical aspect"?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, it probably belongs on the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

However, I think questions may also belong on Robotics if it was somewhat more intelligent - not necessarily requiring both a mechanical aspect as well as an electrical aspect.

While the question you have referred to may be solvable by the users on this site, the application is not robotics, and I think users on this site would be more interested in questions more directly relevant to robotics. Therefore, we should probably reject other questions of this type.

However, **it is not possible to draw a clear line**, so in other cases where it is not clear, we should lean on the side of leniency.

**Note: Just because a question involves both mechanical and electrical aspects, that does not automatically make it a robotics question.** For example, [Mechatronics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechatronics) includes areas such as automotive engineering, transportation systems, consumer products, and other areas. However, we would not consider the design of a "plain old car", train/rail system or aircraft to be robotics, unless they were autonomous and/or RC models. Nor would we consider consumer products such as blenders, dishwashers, washing machines to be robotics.

Comment: OK, similar to what I felt. So questions about purely electrical "robots" _can_ be allowed--depending upon the question and the sophisticatedness of the robot.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, to be considered *Robotics* it has to be a blend of disciplines, covering at least two of software, electronics and electro-mechanical - plus a level of intelligence and/or autonomy.

It's a continuum... at one end things are obviously on-topic, and at the other end obviously off-topic. And the boundary is a huge grey area... which will vary from person to person.

With regards to this question, as my slightly tongue-in-cheek comment suggests, had it been an electro-mechanical analogue clock, rather than an LCD screen, it may well have been enough to creep on-topic. But as it stands, no, not for me.

I am repeatedly told that Arduino is one of the most active tags on Electronics, so there would be the most relevant home.

Furthermore (and as you comment), even if on-topic here, the question is so vague and broad as to be *Not a Real Question* anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A simple test for inclusion might be "a device or machine that can sense and react to its physical environment".  That test could also include something about actuation, if needed.